# Callback function in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, callback, asynccallback

I created a function with the NSURLSession and need to generate a callback to receive the results of asynchronous process.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(yourMutableRequest) { 
    data, response, error in
    // do your stuff here
}
task.resume()
```

How to create a callback function to use in this case? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I am confused, what is not working in your code?

Comment: It's work, but i need a function with callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function to handle the request and return a callback/completionHandler like in the following way:

```
func handler (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) {

}
```

And then call it in the following way:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, 
                                                            completionHandler: handler) 

task.resume()
```

Or if what you want to achieve is use the `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest` function inside another function and return its result you can achieve it using closures as well, like in the following code:

```
func makeRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> ()) {

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { 
            data, response, error in 
                            completionHandler(data: data, response: response, error: error)

    }
}
```

And the you call it like in the following way:

```
self.makeRequest(request) { data, response, error in 
    // do what you want here
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: When will I be brilliant to answer like this ;)